# Django custom user model subclassed (by Zinnia)

Tags: django, zinnia

I have migrated to a Django custom user model (CustomUser) which is into which several other models have foreign key and M2M relationships.  CustomUser is also subclassed by Zinnia's author model (Author) - Zinnia is an excellent third party blogging app.

My issue is that when I access CustomUser via a relationship e.g OtherModel.customuser it returns an instance of CustomUser, but in my views when I access request.User it is an instance of Author.  Since the attributes of Author and CustomUser are identical this in general doesn't make much difference but if I want to test equivalence of user objects in my Views I have to user request.user.id rather than request.user and I instinctively don't like the ambiguity over which model I am dealing with.

Possibly I am better getting over it and leaving things as they are since everything works after a few minor code changes in my views.  In a perfect world, though, I would be referring consistently to the same User model but am uncertain how best to progress.  Any ideas?

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles.CustomUser'
```

models.py (in profiles app)

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    visits = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _('visits'),
        default=0,
        blank=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class OtherModel(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
```

I know the recommendation in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) is to make the relationship with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL rather than directly with the custom user model.  I plan to change that but want to understand what I am doing before launching again into the pain of a migration

author.py (in zinnia app)

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Author(get_user_model()):
    """
    Proxy model around :class:`django.contrib.auth.models.get_user_model`.
    """

    objects = get_user_model()._default_manager
    published = EntryRelatedPublishedManager()
```

In the console get_user_model() returns the profiles.models.CustomUser class

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your problem.

By default, Django does not downcast model instances. For exemple, take the following example:

```
from django.db import models

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(Parent):
    pass

Parent(name="parent").save()
Child(name="child").save()

Parent.objects.all() # will return Parent instances
Child.objects.all() # will return Child instances
```

In your situation, well, you have Zinnia working with `Author` instances, and the rest of your project with `CustomUser` instance. So basically you could downcast every `CustomUser` instance. You can achieve this using an existing django application, such as [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) (which, in my opinion, is a must have when working with concrete inheritance). However, if all your users are not authors, you're screwed

You can also compromise, and implement a manual upcast as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

   # your logic...

    def as_custom_user(self):
        return super(get_user_model(), self)
```

Usage:

```
assert request.user.as_custom_user() == article.author.as_custom_user()
```